# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException | En Google Sign In con Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

Quiero tener autenticación con Google, Facebook y Twitter en mi aplicación en Flutter.

El primer servicio que agregué fué el Sign-In con Google con el plugin google_sign_in en la parte de Flutter, por supuesto usando el plugin de firebase_auth con el que ya integré el acceso con email y contraseña. Posteriormente intenté integrar el Login con Facebook, siguiendo los pasos de su sitio de Developers en conjunto con la documentación de FlutterFire, hice lo mismo con Twitter.

Al correr la aplicación(bastante lenta la compilación por cierto, unos 15-20 minutos), se muestra todo bien aparentemente pero cuando acciono el botón que ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
NabisAuth.instance.googleLogin();
```

Clase propia que ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
  //Google
  Future<UserCredential> googleLogin() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);

    return await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
```

La consola de debug arroja lo siguiente:

```
E/flutter (17174): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
E/flutter (17174): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:157
E/flutter (17174): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17174): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:332
E/flutter (17174): #2      MethodChannelGoogleSignIn.init 
package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/src/method_channel_google_sign_in.dart:28
E/flutter (17174): #3      GoogleSignIn._ensureInitialized 
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:249
E/flutter (17174): #4      GoogleSignIn._callMethod 
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:231
E/flutter (17174): #5      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall 
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:288
E/flutter (17174): #6      GoogleSignIn.signIn 
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:359
E/flutter (17174): #7      NabisAuth.googleLogin 
package:nabis/…/resources/authentication.dart:60
E/flutter (17174): #8      _loginOptions.<anonymous closure> 
package:nabis/…/login/loginscreen.dart:323
E/flutter (17174): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter (17174): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter (17174): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter (17174): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:259
E/flutter (17174): #13     GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:157
E/flutter (17174): #14     GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:374
E/flutter (17174): #15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:350
E/flutter (17174): #16     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:269
E/flutter (17174): #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:305
E/flutter (17174): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:240
```

Lo mismo con Facebook:

Al accionarse:

```
NabisAuth.instance.facebookLogin();
```

Se ejecuta:

```
 //Facebook
  Future<UserCredential> facebookLogin() async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    final FacebookAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken.token);

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  }
```

Debug-Console:

```
E/flutter (17174): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method login on channel ec.dina/flutter_facebook_auth)
E/flutter (17174): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:157
E/flutter (17174): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17174): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:332
E/flutter (17174): #2      FacebookAuth.login 
package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart:32
E/flutter (17174): #3      NabisAuth.facebookLogin 
package:nabis/…/resources/authentication.dart:73
E/flutter (17174): #4      _loginOptions.<anonymous closure> 
package:nabis/…/login/loginscreen.dart:333
E/flutter (17174): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter (17174): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter (17174): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter (17174): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:259
E/flutter (17174): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:157
E/flutter (17174): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:374
E/flutter (17174): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:350
E/flutter (17174): #12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:269
E/flutter (17174): #13     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:305
E/flutter (17174): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:240
E/flutter (17174): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:213
E/flutter (17174): #16     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (17174): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (17174): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (17174): #19     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (17174): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
```

Lo mismo con Twitter:

Al accionarse:

```
NabisAuth.instance.twitterLogin();
```

Se ejecuta:

```
  //Twitter
  Future<UserCredential> twitterLogin() async {
    final String _consumerKey = "cmO5mzo8lnQWg85M77yxym2C5";
    final String _consumerSecret =
        "yQCGxSpGGa09LVG3GIVlpC9c5lrh58367Gcd3ysiwl5s76rDTs";

    final TwitterLogin twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
        consumerKey: _consumerKey, consumerSecret: _consumerSecret);

    final TwitterLoginResult loginResult = await twitterLogin.authorize();

    final TwitterSession twitterSession = loginResult.session;

    final AuthCredential twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: twitterSession.token, secret: twitterSession.secret);

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
  }
```

Debug-Console:

```
E/flutter (17174): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method authorize on channel com.roughike/flutter_twitter_login)
E/flutter (17174): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:157
E/flutter (17174): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17174): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:332
E/flutter (17174): #2      TwitterLogin.authorize 
package:flutter_twitter_login/flutter_twitter_login.dart:105
E/flutter (17174): #3      NabisAuth.twitterLogin 
package:nabis/…/resources/authentication.dart:91
E/flutter (17174): #4      _loginOptions.<anonymous closure> 
package:nabis/…/login/loginscreen.dart:343
E/flutter (17174): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter (17174): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter (17174): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter (17174): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:259
E/flutter (17174): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:157
E/flutter (17174): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:374
E/flutter (17174): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:350
E/flutter (17174): #12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:269
E/flutter (17174): #13     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:305
```

Mi pubspec.yaml

```
name: *****
description: ****** *******

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_core: "0.5.0"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.14.0+2"
  firebase_auth: "^0.18.0+1" 
  firebase_storage: "^4.0.0"
  firebase_analytics: "^6.0.0"
  google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
  flutter_facebook_auth: "^0.2.3"
  flutter_twitter_login: ^1.1.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.27+3
  animate_do: ^1.7.2
  palette_generator: ^0.2.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/img/
    - fonts/Epilogue/

  fonts:
    - family: Epilogue
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Epilogue/Epilogue-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Epilogue/Epilogue-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: fonts/Epilogue/Epilogue-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/Epilogue/Epilogue-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 900
```

Mi Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.23.0-8.0.pre.105, on Linux, locale es_SV.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Mis dependencias del build.gradle del módulo app:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
}
```

Comment: declaraste el hash de la firma de tu app en firebase? igual en la config de facebook? te pide un sha-1 si no me equivoco

Comment: Claro, igual el SHA-256

Comment: si tienes todo eso y el archivo google-services.json de firebase, no deberías tener problema, intenta hacer un flutter clean primero, no te olvides del flutter pub upgrade. Por cierto agrega la configuración de tu archivo gradle para ver que version de android has configurado

Answer (score 0):

- Tienes este tipo de error Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)

Nota: Si no tienes mucho tiempo prueba editando el AppDelegate.h del paso 5

** ¡¡ESTO ES SOLO PARA ERRORES DESPUÉS de actualizar proyectos de Android anteriores a 1.12 !! **

Paso después de actualizar siguiendo la guía: [Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) aplica las siguientes acciones:

1. Actualiza flutter a su última versión estable -> flutter clean
2. Actualice todas sus dependencias (es muy probable que los paquetes tengan o le pidan que agregue nuevos métodos) -> flutter clean
3. Actualice el código y los métodos resultantes de la actualización del paquete.
4. Pruebe flutter run o desde Android Studio |> (algunos paquetes pueden enviarle missingPluginException, pero si está instalado en el móvil) vaya al paso 5.
5. Cree las instalaciones de prueba para Android e IOS si puede (deberían funcionar bien).
   Es probable que en desarrollo con flutter run continúe enviando el error, en mi caso no puedo probar en IOS pero con flutter run se ejecuta tanto para android como para IOS  y el problema se resuelve agregándolo a ios / Runner / AppDelegate.h  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];

   #import <Flutter / Flutter.h>
   #import <UIKit / UIKit.h>

   @interface AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate
   [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
   @Fin

Si después de estos pasos no se puede ejecutar en el paso 4 0 5, verifique que otras dependencias no hayan actualizado sus versiones para que sean compatibles con Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects!. Por ejemplo, si un paquete usa o depende de otro paquete, si puede desinstale uno.
Repita desde el paso 4 nuevamente.